# Extension not found in Angular application

Tags: angular, angular13

In an Angular 13 application I defined the following extension:

```
export { }

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "toNumber", {
  value: function(this: string) {
    return this.trim() ===  '' ? null : Number(this) || null;
  }
});
```

Then I use it the following way:

```
this.userId = value.get('userId')?.toNumber() ?? undefined;
```

But I get the compilation error:

```
Property 'toNumber' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I didn't get this error I a previous Angular version application.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new declaration to your extensions.ts file:

```
export {};

declare global {
    interface String {
        toNumber(): number;
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "toNumber", {...});
```

2. Don't forget to import this file: `import "../extensions";`
   Mode details [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules).